# How do drag an object around on the screen on Android? I don't know how to integrate the example onTouchEvent() code on Android doc website

Tags: java, android

I simply want to touch and drag/move an object around on the screen.

I know there are plenty of given codes out there, using surface holder and imageview matrix. But these codes are not well notated, and I don't know what is going on. I want to just copy and paste them into my own code.

I know there is this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale) on Android Dev website that teaches you how to drag and scale. But for dragging, it only gives an example for the onTouchEvent(), but I don't how I can integrate this method into my MainActivity.java and activity_main.xml files. Specically, in the code snippet, there are mPosX and mPosY, and I don't know how to use these global variables.

I tried creating a new class extending View class and put onTouchEvent().

I know you can use onDraw() and override it to utilize mPosX and mPosY to redraw the object every time your finger moves, but how exactly i don't know. I need some example codes implementing onDraw().

This is the code snippet I am talking about:

```
// The ‘active pointer’ is the one currently moving our object.
private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
// Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

final int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(ev);

switch (action) {
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
    final int pointerIndex = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(ev);
    final float x = MotionEventCompat.getX(ev, pointerIndex);
    final float y = MotionEventCompat.getY(ev, pointerIndex);

    // Remember where we started (for dragging)
    mLastTouchX = x;
    mLastTouchY = y;
    // Save the ID of this pointer (for dragging)
    mActivePointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(ev, 0);
    break;
}

case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
    // Find the index of the active pointer and fetch its position
    final int pointerIndex =
            MotionEventCompat.findPointerIndex(ev, mActivePointerId);

    final float x = MotionEventCompat.getX(ev, pointerIndex);
    final float y = MotionEventCompat.getY(ev, pointerIndex);

    // Calculate the distance moved
    final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
    final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

    mPosX += dx;
    mPosY += dy;

    invalidate();

    // Remember this touch position for the next move event
    mLastTouchX = x;
    mLastTouchY = y;

    break;
}

case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
    mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
    break;
}

case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
    mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
    break;
}

case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {

    final int pointerIndex = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(ev);
    final int pointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(ev, pointerIndex);

    if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
        // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
        // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
        final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
        mLastTouchX = MotionEventCompat.getX(ev, newPointerIndex);
        mLastTouchY = MotionEventCompat.getY(ev, newPointerIndex);
        mActivePointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(ev, newPointerIndex);
    }
    break;
}
}
return true;
```

}

Comment: Whoever downvoted this question need to give a reason. Stop being passive aggressive.

Answer (score 0):

*Create a class MoveViewTouchListener*

```
 public class MoveViewTouchListener
        implements View.OnTouchListener
{
    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
    private View mView;


    public MoveViewTouchListener(View view)
    {
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(view.getContext(), mGestureListener);
        mView = view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private GestureDetector.OnGestureListener mGestureListener = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener()
    {
        private float mMotionDownX, mMotionDownY;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e)
        {
            mMotionDownX = e.getRawX() - mView.getTranslationX();
            mMotionDownY = e.getRawY() - mView.getTranslationY();

            Log.d("imageview"," down");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY)
        {
            mView.setTranslationX(e2.getRawX() - mMotionDownX);
            mView.setTranslationY(e2.getRawY() - mMotionDownY);

            if((distanceX==0)&&(distanceY==0))
            {
                Log.d("imageview"," zoomed");
            }

            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.d("imageview"," tapped");
            return true;
        }

    };
}
```

*In activity call:*

```
ImageView imageView= findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new MoveViewTouchListener(imageView));
```

Comment: Why is there always a return true statement in every onSomething method in the Listener constructor?

Comment: because the overriding method returns boolean value. If onDown or onScroll or any action occurs it should return true.